# Javascript templates vs mvc frameworks

Tags: javascript, шаблоны

**Мой вопрос после правки Krom Ster`ом потерял изначальный смысл.**

Я не спрашивал, почему шаблонизаторы не обновляются, я спрашивал почему "умерло" так много проэктов. Причиной тому стало то, что есть лучшие шаблонизаторы, или же потому, что на смену им пришли mvc фреймворки?
Иними словами, насколько широко сейчас используются эти шаблонизаторы в вебразработке?

Comment: Приведите примеры и тех и тех других, чтобы ваше наблюдение можно было подтвердить или опровергнуть

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&o=desc&p=1&q=template+engine&ref=searchresults&s=updated&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Даже jade 3 дня назад обновился. Что имеет ввиду автор - непонятно.

Comment: Во первых, тема у меня называлась не так, а называлась **javascript templates**
Я вовсе не утвержал, что они не обновляются. Я заметил, что МНОГО из них было закрыто 3-4-5 лет тому назад. Например
https://github.com/archan937/templayed.js
Commits on Jun 22, 2013
http://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/ICanHaz.js 
Commits on Aug 30, 2013 
Ну и так далее.
Вопрос состоял в том не замещаются ли шаблонизаторы mvc framework'ами, или впродолжают использоваться в вебразработке.

Comment: @user3488795, минусов вы нахватали не из-за правки Krom Stern, а из-за того, что это оффтопик.

Comment: Умерло много, появилось тоже. Конкуренция.

Answer (score 2):

[jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/commits/master)

```
Commits on Sep 6, 2015
Commit 69 (v1.0.0-rc.69 - Release Candidate) …
BorisMoore authored 13 days ago
```

[underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commits/master)

```
Commits on Sep 18, 2015
@jdalton
Add MS Edge to karma-sauce runner.
jdalton authored 2 days ago
```

[mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/commits/master)

```
Commits on Sep 19, 2015
@dasilvacontin
Merge pull request #485 from janl/67fe0e5d59bda578ea08526bb58ef0f3db2… …
dasilvacontin authored 14 hours ago
```